# Laravel: How the Auth check works, and the login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I try to have look in `Auth::check()` method to best understanding,
And I didn't understand some things, (I work on laravel 4.2 project)

So this is the check method:

```
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

My question is, How it work, since the fact we call the check method staticly (::) we don't have `AuthManager` object, so it's supposed to be null always not?

2) The login that I use is with remember me token, so I looked at this source code too, I saw that its create a cookie, but when the Laravel framework check that cookie and validate it against the DB?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades or Google "Facade pattern". It's a static class apparently, but isn't :) In the facade's hidden layer, it's always a "singleton", but not static class.The facade create a new instance from a not static class, and when you use the static facade, it call the original instance.

Comment: @esemve thanks, What about my second question, when its happening the check of the remember token?

Comment: yes, it create a token to your database, after  encrypt and send to cookie. if you open the site with cookie, the laravel will check it, and validate it from db.